# A sequence of continuous functions, $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to a discontinuous function $g$, then $\{f_n\}$ does not converges uniformly to $g$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

If a $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of continuous functions, converges pointwise to a discontinuous function $g$, does it imply that $\{f_n\}$ does not converges uniformly to $g$?

Comment: f is a not a continuous function

Comment: You mean a sequence of functions?

Comment: oh yes, sorry if {fn} converges pointwise to a discontinuous function g, does it imply this sequence does not converge uniformly to g?

Comment: It's easy for a sequence of **discontinuous** functions to converge uniformly to a discontinuous function. Perhaps you meant to assume that the functions $f_n$ are continuous functions?

Comment: Use `$\{f_n\}$` to show $\{f_n\}$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks, is this statement true if assume that the functions $f_n$ are continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions such that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to a discontinuous function $g$, then it must be the case that $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly to $g$

---

Proof:

If $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions, then by definition $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall x \in M, \forall n \geq N, |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

So if $f(x)$ is discontinuous at a point, then there exists some $x_o \in M$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f_n(x_o) - f(x_o)| \geq \epsilon$

Hence $\{f_n\}$ must not be uniformly convergent.

---

Example:

$f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$

Each $f_n$ is continuous, and converges pointwise to $0, \forall x \in [0, 1)$ and $1, x =1$